# Which methodology applies: Independent t-test, correlation, and/or simple regression

Tags: regression, correlation, anova, t-test

I am offering an authentic problem related to a research proposal for one of America's military academies. I will convert the context to be as generic as possible. Also, for the sake of brevity, I will offer only the pertinent methodology details.

**Purpose:**

- to demonstrate whether training simulators add significant learning value and can have positive impact on end performance,
- to demonstrate whether incoming MATH SAT scores are a viable predictor of performance, enough for the agency to continue using as an entrance criterion.

**Research Questions:**

1. Do task simulators have any statistically significant impact on the performance of cadets in the training program?
2. Do Math SAT scores have any statistically significant impact on the performance of students in the training program? If so, what is the degree of that relationship?

**Hypotheses:**

Ho1 = Simulators do not have any significant impact on performance.

Ho2 = SAT scores will have a statistically significant impact on performance.   (Note: that this is stated as "will" as opposed to "will not" due to the predominance of research showing SAT scores as benign or                                                                                                                         not being a good predictor in other fields. Is this the correct approach?)

**Population** 
Sample size, n=122 for each of the semesters being tested.

*Special Note: Sample size is equivalent to population size. The Academy's students are a 'captive audience' and relevant data are readily available. Assumption is that this optimizes the confidence level.*

Two sample groups:

a) Group A (Fall 2015) coded 1 (traditional instruction model)
b) Group B (Fall 2016) coded 2 (Simulator supported model)

**Predictor variables:**

a) MATHSAT scores (scale data)

**Dependent Variable:** ACHIEVE (scale data) (achievement on final exam)

**Method:**  **QUESTION: DO THE FOLLOWING METHODS APPEAR ACCURATE? ANY ADVICE?**

1. Testing Ho1 - Comparison of mean scores for ACHIEVE - using Independent 't'-test - parametric - assuming DV distribution is normal. Includes Levene statistic test which will test the assumption of equal variances. This in turn will dictate which statistic to refer to in the t-test table provided in such programs as SPSS.

   - includes testing for skewness of DV distribution, If heavily skewed, then use Mann-Whitney procedure for non-parametric testing.

   Resolution: Compare the means for each of Group A and B
2. Testing Ho2 - **Question: Simple Linear regression or Correlation?**

   a) Group A + MATH SAT versus ACHIEVE

   b) Group B + MATH SAT versus ACHIEVE

Resolution: compare the correlations of each of the groups. Is there a statistically significant relationship between either group's SAT scores and the ACHIEVE performance? If so, compare that relationship as it relates to a group's instructional model.

**Last question as an afterthought:**
SAT scores range from 200 - 800.  If you wanted to determine at what range or level of SAT scores benefit the most from simulator-supported training (Group B) ...... would you use an ANOVA?? Breakdown the SAT scores into groups (i.e. 200-399, 400-599, 600-799 ?)

thank you in advance,
Grayley

Comment: Since there is no randomization,  it seems problematic not to adjust for potential covariates (e.g. ANCOVA) and to do e.g. propensity scores for 201x vs. 201y entry. How huge would effects have to be to pick them up with such a tiny sample size?